# Criar Array usando resultado de um SELECT

Tags: java, mysql, array, array-multidimensional

```
public class TelaGrafico extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conexao = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;


    /**
     * Creates new form TelaGrafico
     */
    public TelaGrafico() {
        initComponents();
        conexao = ModuloConexao.conectar();
        jRadioButtonNatal.setSelected(true);
        jLabelGerarGrafico.setVisible(false);
        jProgressBarGerarGrafico.setVisible(false);

        Calendar calen = Calendar.getInstance();
        int anos = calen.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        jTextFieldAno.setText(Integer.toString(anos));
    }


    //MÉTODO PARA GERAR GRAFICO PELA LOCALIDADE:
    private void GraficoLocalidade() {
        String localidade = jComboBoxLocalidade.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String ano = jTextFieldAno.getText();
        String semIni = jTextFieldSemInicial.getText();
        String semFin = jTextFieldSemFinal.getText();
        switch (jComboBoxDistritos.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 0:
                //NORTE:
                break;
            case 1:
                //SUL:
                break;
            case 2:
                //LESTE:

                String dadosGrafico = "select sem_epi,ipo,ido from tb_indices_leste where localidade='" + localidade + "' and ano='" + ano + "' and sem_epi between '" + semIni + "' and '"+semFin+"'";
                try {
                    pst = conexao.prepareStatement(dadosGrafico);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {}
```

O código termina aqui e esse SELECT acima me retorna a tabela:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| sem_epi | ipo   | ido   |
+---------+-------+-------+
|       1 | 100.0 |  23.1 |
|       2 |  88.9 |  85.0 |
|       3 |  77.8 | 145.3 |
|       4 |  77.8 |   4.0 |
|       5 | 100.0 |   5.0 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

Como crio um Array[][] usando o resultado dessa tabela no JAVA?

Comment: se poderia como é retornado esse Array? ou seja, o código até chegar nesse ponto!

Comment: O código não me retorna nenhum array. O código para nessa consulta(SELECT) e a questão é essa, como criar um array com esses valores dessa tabela.

Comment: Então compartilhe esse código!

Comment: Pronto. Código completo.

Comment: Precisa fazer um classe e criar uma lista dessa classe será que é isso que precisa?

Comment: Acredito que não preciso de outra classe, só preciso pegar esses valores e coloca- los num array[][]. Creio que isso resolve.

Comment: Se vai utilizar esse resultado aonde ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Deu certo demais! Muito obrigado pelo tempo e paciência! Abraço!

Comment: se foi util aceita como resposta da sua pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Pelos comentários o `Array` é do tipo `float` com 5 linhas e 3 colunas mediante a `SQL`, um exemplo:

```
try {
    pst = conexao.prepareStatement(dadosGrafico);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    float[][] items = new float[5][3];
    int line = 0;
    while (rs.next()) 
    {
        items[line][0] = rs.getInt("sem_ip");
        items[line][1] = rs.getFloat("ipo");
        items[line][2] = rs.getFloat("ido");
        line++;
    }
}
```